# How do I install gitlab on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gitlab, gnome

I would really like to give gitlab a try but I keep getting errors. I've followed the instructions on the site but I keep getting errors. Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to test gitlab on your local device is to install it via docker.

https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/#run-the-image

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use this documentation:

[Gitlab installation 16.04](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604)

just don't use the xenial path, use the piped script. I had problems after installing it. This might solve your issues:

```
sudo gem install underscore-rails
sudo gem install gitlab
```

After that I got permissions problems, which were fixed by:

```
chmod 777 /usr/share/gitlab/config/secrets.yml
sudo apt install gitlab
```

With that gitlab got sucessfully installed on Ubuntu 16.10.